# CSS - div positioning issue

Tags: css

I have a wrapper. Inside that wrapper I have 3 divs. I would like #contentOne standing above #contentTwo and contentThree standing on the right side of those two. I am sure someone can help. Thank you in advance for your replies. Cheers. Marc. (This positioning thing is killing me....)

http://jsfiddle.net/Qmrpu/

My HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="contentOne" class="content">contentOne</div>
    <div id="contentTwo" class="content">contentTwo</div>
    <div id="contentThree" class="content">contentThree</div>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
#wrapper{
    width:430px;
    float:left;
    height:auto;
    border:2px solid blue;}

.content{
    border:1px solid black;
    background-color:yellow;
    width:200px;
    height:100px;}

#contentThree{
    height:130px;}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you put them in floated column wrappers?

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="column1" class="column">
        <div id="contentOne" class="content">contentOne</div>
        <div id="contentTwo" class="content">contentTwo</div>
    </div>
    <div id="column2" class="column">
        <div id="contentThree" class="content">contentThree</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.column {
   float: left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xbcxs/

Comment: Thank you Jeff to take time to help me out... The solution proposed by Remibreton and Adam "offer" nevertheless less code modification. But your idea makes my knowledge grow :) So thanks!

Comment: That may be, but never forget that "simple" fixes now often lead to great pain later.  Having a robust HTML structure makes CSS positioning much easier.

Comment: Alright! Do know that your wisdom did not fall into the ear of a deaf man. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

That's how I would've done it. Notice the `position:relative` on the wrapper `div` and `position:absolute; right:0;` on the third `div`.

http://jsfiddle.net/remibreton/7javg/

Comment: Tabernacle ! You are awesome Remibreton. If I could I would give you 1000000 upvotes... thanks a lot :)

Comment: Haha, glad you liked it. Kudos for the quebecker reference ;)

Comment: I believe IE7+ supports `position:absolute` just fine... I had positioning issues with IE6 in the past, but I think a basic use like this one should be fine. Sorry, no means to test at the moment :/

Answer (score 1):

HTML is lacking in providing functions for vertical positioning. They are getting better with newer display values, but you need to limit your audience to only modern browsers. Barring that you need to change the order of the HTML to get the vertical position you want. In this case if you put the 3rd section at the top and gave it a float:right you get what you are after.

http://jsfiddle.net/Qmrpu/1/

Comment: Even less code that the solution given by Remibreton. So if I could I could I would give you 100000000 upvotes. Thanks a lot Adam :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a table for layout?

http://jsfiddle.net/Qmrpu/3/

Comment: Because the height of #contentThree should not be equal to the other divs and a lot of other reasons. Thanks anyway Danny.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="contentThree" class="content">contentThree</div>
    <div id="contentOne" class="content">contentOne</div>
    <div id="contentTwo" class="content">contentTwo</div>
</div>


#wrapper{
width:430px;
float:left;
height:auto;
border:2px solid blue;}

.content{
    border:1px solid black;
    background-color:yellow;
    width:200px;
    height:100px;}

#contentThree{
    height:130px;
    float: right;
}
```